# ValueError: Failed to load delegate from libedgetpu.so.1 docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, tensorflow, tflite

I'm using ubuntu 18.04, on remote host that a coral is connected to.
The docker container is taken from https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/orgs/nvidia/containers/tensorflow/tags (21.09-tf2-py3).
I'm trying to get inferences from a TPU model, but stucked when initializing the TF Lite interpreter:

```
interpreter = pycoral.make_interpreter(model)
```

getting this error:

```
ValueError: Failed to load delegate from libedgetpu.so.1
```

I checked the connection to the coral, it's ok.
I tried looking at the /dev/apex_0 but there is no such dir or file.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

in case you are using USB device, then simply replug device. I experienced similar issue with my one.